# How to transform a dataframe so that values of a column are the column names and column names are rows but unstacked?

Tags: python, pandas, data-transform

I'm comparing two tables to monitor for changes. I need a resulting table that shows a before and after the change per user per attribute changed.

I used the pandas .compare method and below is an example of my current result, but I can't figure out what the next steps would be. If I'm going about this completely wrong feel free to let me know as well.

I currently have a table that looks like this:

| User ID | Name | Favorite | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Steve | Chocolate | Before |
| 2 | John | Chocolate | Before |
| 1 | Stevy | Chocolate | After |
| 2 | John | Vanilla | After |

I need it to look like this:

| User ID | Attribute Changed | Before | After |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | Steve | Stevy |
| 2 | Name | John | John |
| 1 | Favorite | Chocolate | Chocolate |
| 2 | Favorite | Chocolate | Vanilla |

I can eliminate the lines where no changes were made.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe via [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard() # Your df here

out = (
    df
    .pivot(index="User ID", columns="Status")
    .swaplevel(axis=1)
    .stack()
    .reset_index(names=["User ID", "Attribute Changed"])
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
```

out:

```
   User ID Attribute Changed      After     Before
0        1          Favorite  Chocolate  Chocolate
1        1              Name      Stevy      Steve
2        2          Favorite    Vanilla  Chocolate
3        2              Name       John       John
```

Comment: Similar, Melting then pivoting: `df.melt(['User ID', 'Status']).pivot(index=["User ID", "variable"], columns="Status", values='value').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: Eliminate no-changes after pivoting: `df[df.After.ne(df.Before)]`

Comment: Apparently I don't have the reputation to upvote but this worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) like

```py
# import pandas as pd
# df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75922021')[0]

unstacked_df = df.set_index(['User ID','Status']).unstack()

kList = {c[0] for c in unstacked_df.columns} ## {'Name','Favorite'}
dfList = [unstacked_df[k] for k in kList] ## [u__df['Name'],u__df['Favorite']]
conc_df = pd.concat(dfList, keys=kList, names=['Attribute Changed', 'User ID'])

df2Cols = ['User ID', 'Attribute Changed', 'After', 'Before']
df2 = conc_df.reset_index().rename_axis(None,axis='columns')[df2Cols]
```

| `unstacked_df` | `conc_df` | `df2` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: unstack] | [image: concat] | [image: df2] |